# Using multiple blog pages in a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a website for an Outsourcing company in Wordpress. I want to display main services provided by the company in the front page itself in separate boxes. For this, I have selected a WP theme which displays posts in a manner as shown in http://demo.fabthemes.com/Orion/. I am creating posts for each services like Web Development, Designing, Testing etc which will get displayed in HOME page itself.

Now I want to create a page only for blogging. But as I am showing all posts in home page itself I am confused how to do it?

Can I use multiple blog pages in a single website?                     Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem solved. The steps I followed:

1. Create one category **service**.
2. Set the category for all the posts to be displayed in the index page as *service*.
3. Edit the index page template and add the code instead of the code which is written for fetching the posts.

   `query_posts('category_name=service&showposts=10');

   while (have_posts()) : the_post();

   the_content();`

   where **category_name** is the name of the category and **showposts** is the number of posts you want to display.
4. Create a custom page template http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates. For eg: **My custom page**.
5. Copy the code for index.php to the custom page template.
6. Edit the code part which is used to fetch the posts. And add the following code.

   `query_posts('category_name=uncategorized&showposts=50');

   while (have_posts()) : the_post();

   the_content();`
7. Create a page for blogging. For example apage named **Blog**. Now set the page template for the page as **My custom page**.

Now **index** page will lists only the posts under the category *service* and the **Blog** page will displays all other posts.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta use categorie's.

1. Add a categorie in your wordpress admin panel

2a. Copy your category-template file and change name on top of the php-file.

2b. Or don't copy the php file and use a filter directely in your category-template where it checks the selected page with the right category. Something like

```
if ( is_page('page_slug') ) {  query_posts('cat=4'); }
```

3. If u choose 2a (which i mostly use), then you can add this line in the while loop of your php file:  `query_posts('cat=4');`.

Next u can make a new page in your admin panel and select your new category template file.

You can find the number of the category by hovering over the category and check the link on your bottom left screen

Hope this is clear enough

Comment: I don't have a page template option.

Comment: You gotta make a file on your fpt. I prefer editting the category files via Filezilla, Download the file, edit it in notpad++ and copy the file back with a different name